# Zuul: Uploading file through RestTemplate

Tags: java, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I try to create simple Spring Cloud model: Zuul, Eureka, MyService1, MyService2.

MyService1 & Myservice2 register by Eureka.

MyService1 configured:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableFeignClients
public class ServiceOne {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceOne.class, args);
    }
}
```

and has RestTemplate for uploading file into MyService2.

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.put("file", Arrays.asList(new Object[] {new ClassPathResource("testfile.txt")}));
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
restTemplate.postForObject("http://service2", requestEntity, String.class);
```

MyService2 configured:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ServiceTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceTwo.class, args);
    }
}
```

and has RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = AppRestController.REST_URL)
public class RootController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/context}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> upload (MultipartFile file) {
        ...

    }
}
```

Request recieved by

> RootController

, but

> file == null.

I built **working** simple SpringBoot application containing RestTemplate:

```
public class TestRestTemplate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.put("file", Arrays.asList(new Object[] {new ClassPathResource("testfile.txt")}));
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        //Zuul address
        restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8761/service2", requestEntity, String.class);
    }
}
```

What do i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is too late to answer, in case if someone else would have a similar problem.
I supouse that the problem here:
map.put("file", Arrays.asList(new Object[] {new ClassPathResource("testfile.txt")}));
it should looks like:

> map.add("files", new ClassPathResource("testfile.txt"));

here more detail:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload